# How can one gain the Dota 2 achievements?

Tags: achievements, dota-2

How can one get the achievements listed in the Dota 2 section of the Library? If I click on "View all achievements" I just land on my profile page...

[image: Dota 2 achievement section]

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to unlock achievements in Dota 2 as of now.

What you see are just placeholders, they've been there for a long time but they don't really exist in-game.

[Response from Valve employee on the question](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/828938532617208018/) (29 May 2013 3:34am):

> Dota 2 does not currently have achievements.